# Is the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{-2n-1}{n^2+n}$ Cesaro summable?

Tags: real-analysis, cesaro-summable

The sequence of terms converges to $0$, as the the sequence is convergent in the standard sense. One can quickly prove this as $\left|(-1)^{n-1}\frac{-2n-1}{n^2+n}\right|=\left|\frac{2n+1}{n^2+n} \right|\leq \left|\frac{2}{n+1}\right|<\varepsilon$, but this doesn't necessarily imply that the *series* is Cesaro summable though. Any insights?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2n+1}{n^2+n}$ is convergent in the standard sense, therefore the sequence $a_n=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2n+1}{n^2+n}$ is Cesaro summable.

Comment: @Gae.S. Oh I see, completely forgot about that. Are there any examples where the sequence of terms is cesaro convergent to $0$ but the series isn't cesaro summable?

Comment: What does it mean for a sequence to be Cesaro convergent to $0$?

Comment: it means $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots a_k}{k}=0$

Comment: Like, $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac1k\sum_{n=1}^k n^{-1}=0$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac1k\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{h=1}^j j^{-1}=\infty$ ?